# Draw calls in Unity 3d

Tags: unity, textures, performance, materials, texture-atlas

I have only 20 materials in my game (19 are made with textures atlas). But the Setpass call is 72. I don't understand why. I want to know how to decrease the number of SetPass call.
 
This is a brief summary about the game: 
Houses vertex attributes : from 43 to 270. They are low poly houses. Props too. 
 No normal maps. Only diffuse and ambient occlusion maps. Only the Playable character has his own texture. There 45 houses models. I have 19 textures atlas. 
 In the game, some houses are assembled to formed another house (modular houses). And I assembled 10 to 18 houses to form a BLOC (a piece of town). 
For all the gameObects, SHADER is Universal Render Pipeline. I didn't edit anything, I use the default properties. 
In the game, Bloc of houses are put together 3 by 3 and randomly to form town like (SUBWAY SURFER)
In Unity playmode :
 Tris : 54.9k 
 Verts: 80k
 Batches : 466 
Saved by batching : 0
 Shadow caster: 0
 Visible Skinned meshes: 1

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why you could happen and you don't provide much information. Just a wild guess: Are you modifying material properties with code? Like color, for example?

Comment: No, I don't modify material properties with code. I don't have transparent shader.

Comment: As Philipp says, we'll need more information about how you've set up your project to be able to help you here. It could be you have more models/vertex data than will fit into a single batch even with shared materials, or you're using materials with batching disabled, or your models are not static so the engine can't use static batching, or you've inadvertently copied the materials somewhere, or you have many lights, or you're using a lot of skinned meshes which don't batch, or you're rendering in a queue that uses sorting, or you have multiple cameras, or or or...

Comment: It's a 3D platform game, an infinite runner game. I have only one light (the directional light), one camera. I made many blocs of house. I make them Prefab. Each bloc contains 10 or 18 houses and some props. Each house has no more than 300 vertices. I use texture atlas (1 texture for 6 houses). So platforms are generated procedurally. But houses and props are not Static. I don't use Skinned mesh. I don't render in a queue that uses sorting.
Nb: in the game Stats :
Tris : 49 k
Verts : 71k
Batches : 394
Saved by batching : 0

Comment: We're starting to get somewhere. How many vertex attributes do your houses/props have (position, normal, tangent, texture coordinates, vertex colour, etc.)? Can you edit your question to walk us through the steps required to reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of your problem, so we can test out the problem locally and test potential solutions?

Comment: Houses vertex attributes from 43 to 270. They are low poly houses. Props too. No normal maps. Only diffuse and ambient occlusion maps.  Only the Playable character has his own texture. There 45 houses models. I have 19 textures atlas. In the game, some houses are assembled to formed another house (modular houses). And I assembled 10 to 18 houses to form a bloc as a piece of town. For all the gameObects, SHADER is  Universal Render Pipeline. I didn't edit anything, I use the default properties. 
In bloc, Bloc of houses are put together 3 by 3 and randomly to form town

Comment: I'll repeat: Can you **edit your question** to walk us through the steps required to reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of your problem, so we can test out the problem locally and test potential solutions?

Comment: Bear in mind that the number of draw calls isn't just separate materials, but each material on *each object*. That is, even if two objects have the same material, they will be separate draw calls. Unity attempts to optimize around this through batching meshes, but your game stats show no batching is happening. Thus, your issue really boils down to "why isn't it batching?"

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is easy to diagnose yourself. Just turn off objects in your scene (uncheck the box next to their name in the inspector to deactivate their GameObject) one at a time and watch how the stats change. If the SetPass calls drop off a lot after disabling a particular object, you've found your culprit. Then you just need to investigate the configuration of that object.